# Не работают классы в поиске(

Tags: javascript

Мне тут люди на форуме сказали, что использовать
**getElementsByClassName** не стоит, так как это устаревший метод.
Вместо него порекомендовали **querySelector и querySelectorAll.**

Но как найти классы css при помощи эту двух методов?

```js
alert find = main.querySelector('second')
alert(find);
```

```css
.main{
background: orange; elem.querySelector(css)
}

.second {
font-size: 2vmax;   
margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="second">
Text
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: надо перед поставить querySelector('.second') и все заработает?
а по поводу совета, лучше использовать querySelector, чем getElementsByClassName?

Comment: Сколько нужно времени, чтобы это проверить? Используйте что хотите.

Comment: Меня интересует мнение экспертов, а не то, что я хочу использовать.
Так что лучше использовать?

Comment: Используйте что хотите. Важно уметь этим правильно пользоваться.

Comment: _«что лучше использовать?»_ - то что подходит к задаче. Используются и те, и другие методы. Они возвращают разный тип результата. Выбор должен делаться **рассудком**, а не по совету дяди из интернета. Программирование это создание решений (умственная деятельность), а вовсе не бездумное-механическое выполнение действий без понимания их смысла. Любой другой совет кроме "исследуй и думай самостоятельно" тут будет вредным.

Answer (score 1):

У вас небольшая путаница в коде. Попробуйте так (`.querySelector()` можно использовать и с документом, и с элементами, и не забывайте добавлять точку перед селектором класса):

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const second = main.querySelector('.second');
alert(second);
```

```css
.main{
  background: orange;
}

.second {
  font-size: 2vmax;   
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="second">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а мне тут говорили, что  обращаться к элементам по глобальному id плохая идея.
Как правильно обращаться к элементам?

Comment: Обращение через document это глобальное обращение?

Comment: Так а здесь нет ни id, ни обращения по id — мы просто называем переменную похожим образом.

Comment: А как определить нормальное обращение к элементам от глобального?

Comment: Нет, мы просто сначала ищем во всём документе, а потом в родительском элементе, это демонстрация возможных применений. Можно оба раза использовать документ, но поиск внутри родительского элемента помогает сузить область поиска.

Comment: А как определить глобальное обращение к элементу?
Пожалуйста покажите мне глобальное обращение)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Наверное, старое наследие: элементы c id создают в объекте window свойства, одноимённые id и по ним иногда обращаются к элементам. querySelector не имеет к этому отношения, любое обращение к этому методу не несёт ничего предосудительного.

Comment: Значит лучше использовать всегда querySelector?
Как я понимаю это более новый продвинутый метод поиска элементов?

Comment: Он просто самый универсальный — с его помощью можно искать и по классам, и по id, и по всем остальным CSS-свойствам, поэтому многие перешли на него. В старых методах тоже ничего плохого нет, если уметь ими пользоваться. У результатов getElementsByClassName и querySelectorAll есть отличие (один возвращает живую коллекцию, другой статическую), но вам, наверное, на первом этапе обучения это различие может быть неважно. Если хотите, почитайте документацию к обоим методам на MDN, чтобы разобаться в деталях.

Comment: Cпасибо огромное! последний вопрос getElementsByClassName возвращает живую или неживую коллекцию?

Comment: Живую: [`Document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) — это может быть полезно или наоборот может запутать, в зависимости от ситуации)

Comment: Ооо, да вы эксперт высшего разряда. Если не секрет, то сколько лет надо учиться, чтобы достичь вашего уровня.

Comment: В данном случае ничего экспертного тут нет)

Comment: Если не секрет, то сколько лет вы изучали js и по сколько часов в день)?

Comment: У меня нет такой статистики, учил для своих личных нужд постольку-поскольку)

Comment: а сколько лет учили)?

Comment: Я с ним познакомился давно, когда он ещё был маленький. С тех пор просто всё время обновлял знание.

Comment: Значит примерно 8-15 лет =)
Да, срок хороший =)

Answer (score 1):

1. Научиться писать селекторы: надо `.second`.
2. Не писать мусор в скрипте: что за `alert find =`?
3. Не использовать несуществующие переменные: `main`.
4. Не писать мусор в стилях: `elem.querySelector(css)`.
5. Объявлять переменные явно.
6. Метод `getElementsByClassName` не устаревший, они просто для разных целей нужны.

```js
var main = document.querySelector('.main')
var elem = main.querySelector('.second')
console.log(elem);

var el = document.querySelector('.second')
console.log(el);
```

```css
.main{
  background: orange;
}

.second {
  font-size: 2vmax;   
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="second">
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А покажите правильный пример моего кода без мусора. Запомню на всю жизнь как писать правильно, если покажете)

Comment: Добавил 2 варианта.

Comment: А какой вариант лучше через Document или через родительский элемент div?

Comment: Они разные. Конкретно в данном случае лучше `document.querySelector('.second')` или `document.querySelector('.main .second')` в зависимости от задачи.